# only firsts few iteration appears in the rendered image

Tags: rendering, modifiers, objects, image, screw-modifier

I made a rope by iterating screwed circles. In render mode everything is fine but in the rendered image most of iterations dissapears. How to fix it?[image: circle007 and circle004 are the ropes]

Comment: Is there a reason you keyframed the iterations? If not, just click the little diamond to the right of the iterations box.

Comment: that was it! Thank you very much